# Convergence in distribution space and tempered distribution space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I can neither prove nor disprove the following claim.

Let $u_k \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ and $u_k \to 0$ in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$.
Then, $u_k \to 0$ in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$.

I expect this is false.
Define $u_k := \frac{d^k\delta_k}{dx^k} \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. $\langle u_k, \varphi \rangle := (-1)^k\frac{d^k\varphi}{dx^k}(k)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Then, it is clear that $u_k \to 0$ in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$. I expect $u_k \nrightarrow 0$ in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$, however, I cannot prove it.

I would be grateful if anyone could give me some advice.

Comment: $\mathcal S'$ is the dual of the Fréchet space $\mathcal S$ of all smooth functions with all norms $\|f\|_n=\sup\{(1+|x|)^n |f^{(k)}(x)|: x\in\mathbb R, k\le n\}$ finite. If a sequence $u_k$ converges in the weak$^*$ topology of $\mathcal S'$ then it is equicontinuous by Banach-Steinhaus, i.e., there are $n\in \mathbb N$ and $c>0$ such that, for all $k\in\mathbb N$, one has $|u_k(f)|\le c \|f\|_n$. In particular, for the sequence $u_k$ you propose, you can estimate the $(n+1)$-th derivative of $f$ by $\|f\|_n$. This should be a good starting point to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac1k e^{t^2} 1_{|t|< k^2}$ converges to $0$ in $D'$ but not in $S'$ (pairing with $e^{-x^2}$).

It is true that
$\delta^{(k)}(x-k)$ doesn't converge to $0$ in $S'$, take $\phi \in C^\infty_c$ constant $=1$ on $[-1/2,1/2]$ and $=0$ on $|x|>3/2$, let $\psi(x) = \frac{\phi(x)}{1-x}$ and look at $\varphi(x)=\sum_{k\ge 0}2^{-k} \psi(x-k)$, all the derivatives are rapidly decreasing, but $\varphi^{(k)}(k)=2^{-k}\psi^{(k)}(0) = 2^{-k}k!$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understood, but I think defining $u_k(t) := e^{x^2} \chi_{\{j < t < j+1\}}$ makes this problem simpler. In my question, I claimed $\frac{d^k\delta_k}{dx^k} \to 0$ in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$, and I didn't claim $\frac{d^k\delta}{dx^k} \to 0$ in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathcal{R})$

Comment: Oops I edited again, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your editing. I would be grateful if you tell me hint to construct such a Schwartz function. My English is bad. Please forgive me if there are any grammatical errors or confusing parts.

Comment: I constructed a Schwartz function which seems ok